# How to check if the number is present in either of three sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Excel version:** Mac 2022 v. 16.66.1
**Type of problem:** Function

Hello.
I seek for a function that I shall insert in column `OA?` that would:

*for each cell in column D, E, G or H of the current spreadsheet check if the numerical value is present in either column I, K or L of spreadesheet "ACS.xlsx", B of spreadsheet "ELSEVIER.xlsx", or C of spreadsheet "SPRINGER.xlsx". If so, write "YES" in the corresponding cell of OA column, else write "NO".*

For the clarity, I attach screenshot. Thank you in advance!

I tried with this formula, but it also counts empty cells....

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D3, '[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$J:$J, 0)), 
ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3, '[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$J:$J, 0)), 
ISNUMBER(MATCH(G3, '[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$J:$J, 0)), 
ISNUMBER(MATCH(H3, '[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$J:$J, 0)), 
ISNUMBER(MATCH(D3, '[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$L:$L, 0)), 
ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3, '[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$L:$L, 0)), 
ISNUMBER(MATCH(G3, '[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$L:$L, 0)), 
ISNUMBER(MATCH(H3, '[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$L:$L, 0)))), "YES", "NO")
```

[image]

Comment: Using the `MATCH()` function is inefficient, since you don't care _where_ the value is, only _if_ it exists at all - accordingly `COUNTIF()` would be more efficient (since it doesn't need to be error trapped), e.g. `=IF(OR(AND(D3<>"",COUNTIF(D3,'[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$J:$J&'[ACS.xlsx]Journal Vitals'!$L:$L)),...` a single function to check for the presence of the non-blank D3 value in either column J or column L

Comment: @SpectralInstance Ehh... Can you give a complete example? I am not sure whether I understand it.

Comment: The information you provided is neither complete (looking across 3 files but referencing only 1 of them in the formula posted) nor consistent (the narrative mentions columns I, J & K in the 1st file but your formula is referencing columns J & L) so all I can do is clarify that my suggestion is, for each value sought, to use an `AND` function to combine a test for 'non-blankness' with a test for `COUNTIF` returning a value greater than 0 (if I had this problem, I would be using PQ to consolidate data from the 3 files and then 'lookup' against that imported data)